# What are the best tools for manually annotating textual topic segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, annotation

I checked this [old question](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-tools-for-manually-annotating-a-text-corpus-with-entities-and-relationships) on tools for text corpus annotation and there are many good tools there, however the tools there seem not to cover my problem.

I have a linear text segmentation problem, in which a text needs to be segmented in different sections (topics). I'm building a model for it, but I have no training data. Therefore, the team decided to manually label some text, by annotating blocks in the text that represent each section. I tried some NER or POS labelling tools, but they are not very convenient for selecting several lines and paragraphs to annotate a label.

Is there a good tool for human annotation of text segmentation?

Comment: There is a simple yet powerful tool called [BRAT](http://brat.nlplab.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a suitable tool, so I made a tool for textual topic segmentation.

To anyone interested in this question, I forked YEDDA's entity recognition project and changed it, accordingly. You can check it here in GitHub: https://github.com/ThiagoSousa/YEEDASeg. My project is called YEDDASeg.

Edit: People mentioned to use BRAT, but it is good to select a word and tag with with a label. My case is a bit more complicated, because it can be many paragraphs. In YEDDASeg, you basic just click on the text and press a key to label a topic in the text. It is simpler for this purpose.